Are questions about websites central to the community on topic?
Today, someboday asked a question about a feature on Bitcointalk.org: Why can't some members vote on bitcointalk.org?
I am not sure if there is a consensus here, whether such questions about web-communities such as Bitcointalk or /r/bitcoin are on-topic, and I would like to read what you think: Arguments for and against welcome.

One thing this opens up is a debate about which sites are relevant enough to be supported.  If we say we allow questions about features about bitcointalk.org, who decides that bitcointalk.org is allowed, but mycoolbitcoinwebsite.com isn't?  That to me is the biggest risk of going down this road.
And in the end, I think the person asking the question wants to find the best answer to their question.  Isn't it more likely that they'll find a bitcointalk expert on bitcointalk.org rather than bitcoin.stackexchange.com, no matter how good it is?


Is it on topic?

Maybe. The topic page is unclear on this point.

Should it be on topic?

No. There are a huge number of questions that could be asked about external websites, most of which have support contacts or a discussion area. It's difficult to keep those questions up to date when said websites change their policies.
Lastly, more than anything, I don't want to read questions/debates about the policy of website X.

Love it or hate it, BitcoinTalk has always acted as an early surrogate of Bitcoin SE. We often link to posts there and the knowledge therein can be invaluable. 
I have no issue with making exceptions for BCT if and only if:

Website policy is not the majority of questions
Altcoin queries are kept to a minimum
We go on a case by case basis for other sites (exchanges, tools etc)

"Is this a common query" needs to be front of mind.

What do you mean with "Altcoin queries are kept to a minimum"? Altcoins are on-topic on Bitcoin.SE.

@Murch I'm aware altcoins aren't off-topic as I check the altcoin tag from time to time. I was referring more to questions like "why do my BCT Altcoin posts get deleted from (self-moderated) topics?" and "is XXXcoin a scam?". There's a huge divide in quality at BCT between the Bitcoin and Altcoin sub-forums' posts and community motivations.

Ah, I mistook your post to mean that questions about the Altcoin area of BCT would be kept to a minimum on our side. Now it makes sense to me.
